# C++ warning: pragma once in main file

Tags: c++

I'm have an issue with compiling my program with g++ 8.3. I have approx 10 classes in a program. These classes are placed in header files and their full definitions are in `.cpp` files. I'm including these classes the same way as in this code:

main.cpp:

```
#include "CPerson.h"

int main()
{
    CPerson person1(10 , "Peter");
    CPerson person2(20 , "James");
    person1.Print();
    person2.Print();
    return 0;
}
```

CPerson.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CPerson{
protected:
    int m_Age;
    string m_Name;
public:
    CPerson( const int age , const char * name ) :
    m_Age(age), m_Name(name){}
    void Print(){
        cout << "Hello Im " << m_Name << " - " << m_Age << "years old" << endl;
    }
};
```

When I try to compile this C++ program with the following command:

> g++ main.cpp CPerson.h

I get this message:

> warning: #pragma once in main file

Is here anything I can do about this, or is it just bug in the g++ compiler?

**SOLVED:**

You need to compile only .cpp files with declarations of methods of each class thats defined in Class.h

Comment: You don't need to mention .h files when invoking the compiler.

Comment: `g++ main.cpp` is sufficient, As a beginner I'm not sure you should be so quick to suspect g++ of having bugs.

Comment: One addition to @HolyBlackCat. If You want to specify a path to some headers use the `-I` option. Example: `g++ -I "some path" main.cpp -o hello.out`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You get the warning because you are compiling a file that contains `#pragma once`. `#pragma once` is only intended to be used in headers, and there is no need to compile headers; hence the warning. Solution: Don't compile headers.

Comment: There may be a need to compile a header. E.g. I want to check if my header's syntax is correct by compiling it with -fsyntax-only, and I get this warning too.

Comment: How it possible to `Don't compile headers` ,remove all the `#include` ???

Comment: @Guichi `How it possible to Don't compile headers` Simply don't pass header files to a compiler. Example: `g++ source.cpp` is good, `g++ source.hpp` is bad.

Comment: @eerorika the `#include "source.hpp"` is required to make the file compile.  when the header is `#inclued` it will be compiled anyway. How to `Don't compile headers` I did not put header as a arg in `g++`, put it as for `#include` instead

Comment: Might want to take a look: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47857.